# My "msil" ClickOnce application launched from IE will run as 32-bit on 64-bit Windows

Tags: 64-bit, clickonce

I am wrestling with an issue I cannot understand. We have a ClickOnce deployment of a WPF application in Azure blob storage.  The processor architecture is everywhere "msil" in this deployment.  When it gets run from IE, it runs as a 32bit application on AMD64 computers.  The desired behavior would be to run as 64 bit.  Could someone please enlighten on where should I look to fix this problem?

I already managed to go through the hoops to build the assemblies as x64 and create the ClickOnce deployment as amd64.  This combo will run as 64 bit.  The desired behavior is to still have it "msil" so it can run as either 32-bit or 64-bit, depending on the operating system it will be running on.

Comment: Are you running 64 bit IE when you download the application?  If IE is launching it, it might be bound by that environment?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/32-or-64-bit-version-of-internet-explorer/d8fb9b92-778b-4475-8f33-8f3791423259?auth=1

Comment: Thanks very much for your responses!  I modified IE 11's settings to launch 64-bit tabs and restarted the computer.  I verified with procexp64.exe that IE's tabs are now 64-bit processes.  What I'm seeing now is that the 64-bit dfsvc.exe (ClickOnce) launches the 32-bit image of my msil application.  So turning IE into a 64-bit app did not fix the problem.